# Herringbone maple tabletop warped

Tags: tabletop

I  flopped a tabletop glueup.  Clamped only from above, table saw was .5 degrees off. And the 32 pieces on each side create a "bowl" in the middle of about 1/4in. Ouch. What can I  do , if anything,  to straighten it out?

Comment: Can you post some photos of the tabletop?  (Both showing the overall design and focusing on the defect - lay a straightedge across it.)  How it is constructed can make a big difference in what your options are for fixing it.

Comment: Sand or plane it flat, your only options at this point unless you want to try to take it apart and correct every piece. Yeah I wouldn't either :-) BTW many tables that look like this are veneered, not made from solid wood, for some very good reasons.

Comment: Need pix, Andrea.  Any chance of cutting the tabletop into strips and gluing back together square to get rid of or mitigate the "bowl" shape?